# Telerik RadSlideView (WP7) with MVVM

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, binding, mvvm, telerik

I'm currently trying to use Telerik's `RadSlideView` to display my images. I've followed the code in http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/radslideview-gettingstarted.html and they work perfectly well, but on the other hand I'd like to bind to **real objects** *(with a variety of properties)* and not just `string` arrays.

My main reason for wanting to do this is to allow the `RadSlideView` to show more than just images. I'd like to have descriptions, and other stuff! (which all belong to a specific object) I know this question might be kinda obscure, but if you could give me any ideas, it'd help me a long way :) cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page you linked there's a sample with "complex" databinding, look at the ItemTemplate property where there's the image with a description :

```
   <telerikPrimitives:RadSlideView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="None" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerikPrimitives:RadSlideView.ItemTemplate>
```

Is it not what you want ?

Comment: Yup, apparently they just released the 2012 Q1 version, which supports complex data-binding. I was using the 2011 Q3 version previously. Many thanks! :)

Comment: Telerik also has support forums available at http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/windows-phone.aspx if you have further questions.